# Divergent sequence proof.

Tags: calculus

Let $\; (a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence such that  $\; \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} = \infty$

Prove that $\; \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \;\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = \infty$

Well, my head tells me that I need to bound the sum sequence from below by a sequence that diverges into infinity, but I can't figure out how.

Can I get some insight?

Comment: What does the notation $\lim\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ mean?

Comment: Use the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem

Comment: Weird notation. You probably just mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty$, right? Or even just $a_n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The summation term is the average value of $a_n$. By the definition of limit to infinity, for all reals $r$ there exist an integer $N$ such that $a_n>r$ for all $n \geq N$. This means that for all $n>2N$, the average value must be at least $\frac{r}{2}$. So the summation sequence eventually stays above any given real permanently, and so the limit is infinity.

Comment: What if e.g. $a_n \ll -r$ for $n < N$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be any positive integer. There exits $n_0$ such that $a_n >N$ for $n \geq n_0$. Now $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_n =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_0 -1}a_n+\sum\limits_{k=n_0}^{n} a_n>\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_0 -1}a_n+(n-n_0+1)M$. Divide by $n$ and let $n \to \infty$. You get $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_n >M-1$ for $n$ sufficiently large because  $ \frac  1 n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_0-1} a_n \to 0$. Can you complete the proof.